# Errors while working with files in C in Visual studio 2010 IDE

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w");
   fprintf(fp, "This is testing...\n");
   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

i am new to Visual studio but heard that its an awesome IDE for C/C++ i did some basic C and it worked really fine now i have a project to do and i am seriously stuck at this point i am NOT ABLE TO WORK WITH OPENING AND CLOSING FILES IN C when i compile this code it gives me a error

see these images

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6092/6311309820_9c06ef4f0a.jpg

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6221/6310789365_4298e416bd.jpg

DEBUG OUTPUT:::

```
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Anunay\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FredEx Challenge\Debug\FredEx Challenge.exe', Symbols loaded.
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FredEx Challenge.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
FredEx Challenge.exe has triggered a breakpoint
```

HELP ME OUT I'm IN A TIME BOUND Crisis

Comment: When you created your project in Visual Studio what type did you select? From the looks of your posted code a simple "Win32 Console Application" would be correct.

Comment: What do you think "/tmp/test.txt" means on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the program is unable to create the file `/tmp/test.txt`, probably because there no `/tmp` directory exists, or writing is not permitted.

In such cases, `fopen()` returns NULL, and since the program does not check the return value, it will segfault (or whatever Windows calls it this year).

Make sure you know what the default drive is when the program runs.  Or better yet, remove the path and use the current working directory by specifying the filename as `test.txt`.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fp = fopen ("test.txt", "wt");  // t = text mode
   if (!fp)
   {
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d creating file\n", errno);
        return 1;
   }
   fprintf (fp, "This is testing...\n");
   fclose (fp);
   return 0;
}
```